# how to display dates from starting to end date from current month using php?

Tags: php, html

I can display dates from start to end date from stored data in mysql, but I want to display current month dates from 1st to end date of this month in form of

1
2
3
4
.
.
.
.
.
31

Is this possible?

Comment: don't be shy, share with us what you tried ;)

Comment: i havent tried anything when i m thinking about it i m not getting solution so thats i asks

Answer (score 2):

Refer to PHP `cal_days_in_month`

[As explained here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)

This function will return the number of days in the month of year for the specified calendar.

`int cal_days_in_month ( int $calendar , int $month , int $year )`

And an example:

```
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2003); // 31
echo "There were {$number} days in August 2003";
```

Use a loop to display a count of the number of days

Answer (score 1):

If you want all days in the month, try this loop where date("t") give you the numerical last day of the month, and we know the first day is always 1.

```
$last = date("t");
for($i=1; $i<= $last; $i++) echo "$i ";
```

Answer (score 1):

For the PHP part, this might help you:

```
// Get the current date
$today = getdate();

// Get the number of days in current month
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $today['mon'], $today['year']); 

// Print the dates
for ($i = 1; $i <= $days_in_month; $i++) {
  echo ' ' . $i;
}
```

Styling and output is another task, this is just to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

```
yes. it is possible.
please, use below php code. it can work for php 4.1 and higher.
<?php
$number = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m'), date('Y'));
for($i=1;$i<=$number;$i++)
    echo $i.'<br>';
?>
```